# Listen to "back" key pressed in a Fragment

Tags: java, android

I use a `Fragment` to let the user enter information in my Android application. If information has been entered, I want a warning to be sent to the user if he presses the "back" key. If he confirms he wants to abandon the changes, the `Fragment` has to be popped. If he cancels the abandon, the `Fragment` should remain as it is.

I already tried to implements `onKeyListener` to my `Fragment` with an `onKey` callback function. But it is never executed.

How can I do?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try something like this. (I haven't been able to test this)

In your activity, override `onBackPressed()`:

```java
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {       
    Fragment frag = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.your_container);

    if(frag instanceof TheFragmentYouAreTalkingAbout) {
        ((TheFragmentYouAreTalkingAbout)frag).showConfirmGoBackDialog();
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

The `showConfirmGoBackDialog()` method should create a dialog box. In this dialog you can put a listener on the confirm/OK button that will call `getFragmentManager().popBackStack();` if pressed, otherwise do nothing.

Comment: you might as well put this code in the Fragment, as that has the same override available, and then you'd know you're in the proper fragment.

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer not to use instanceof comparison.

So my solution is to provide a tag when commiting fragment transaction. Then you can find fragment by tag:

```
private void showMyFragment(){
    Fragment fragment = new MyFragment();
    FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    ft.replace(R.id.container, fragment, MY_FRAGMENT_TAG);
    ft.commit();
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    MyFragment fragment = (MyFragment)findFragmentByTag(MY_FRAGMENT_TAG);

    if (fragment != null) {
        fragment.showConfirmation
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```